# New to vim - MAC OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

I am new to vim, and I just followed [this setup tutorial](http://thedrearlight.com/blog/tmux-vim.html), but something went wrong. I am a ruby developer and I am not getting a a ruby highlighting syntax. I have installed janus, before with pathogen I had syntax highlighting but not know.

Also I am using the solarized theme the guy suggested but there is no difference now (in color) between folders and files in my terminal when listing a directory.

Could somebody tell me if I can install pathogen with janus? WIll this break my vim?
Thanks!

Comment: What went wrong? Give us an error message, system details, etc.

Comment: Is this question part of a SEO campaign? The only keyword missing is "homebrew".

Comment: Vundle is the vim package manager to use. Forget about the rest. Seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't install anything (and don't install Janus).
2. Run `$ vimtutor` in your terminal. As many times as needed (and don't install Janus).
3. Once you feel ready to use Vim for day-to-day coding, install MacVim which is built with a better feature set than the default Vim. It comes with a CLI executable so you can use it in your terminal and in tmux (and don't install Janus).
4. Install the [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) package for better, more up-to-date Ruby support (and don't install Janus).
5. Don't install Janus. This thing is a pile of crap that will make your life overly complicated, hook you on plugins that may or may not be the best for you needs and prevent you from actually learning Vim properly in exchange of an artificially flattened learning curve.
6. Decide for a plugin/runtimepath management solution (VAM, vundle or plain Pathogen) and choose your plugins yourself according to *your* needs (and don't install Janus).
7. If you have problems with Solarized, take a look at their issue tracker and their wiki. It is fragile and you need some work to set it up correctly (and… you know the rest).

Comment: is Janus that bad? I already installed it and followed most of the steps of the tutorial. I will just remove it I guess

Comment: It depends on why you have decided to use Vim in the first place. If you feel that Vim will make you more efficient, that its philosophy is intriguing or, well… that its proverbial learning curve is worth it then Janus is the opposite of what you need. If you decided to use Vim because it's all the rage on the internet right now and you are not ready to commit much (waiting until the next internet trend) then by all means go with Janus/SPF13/whatever.